# Problem for ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

I have  many buttons inside the app, and want to scrooll just buttons but, I can't use a ScrollView just for buttons,Is it possible?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.motor.MotorFragment">
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

  <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/Motorvid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="700dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="700dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

There is many buttons here to scrooll:

```
  <Button
    style="@style/AppTheme.RoundedCornerMaterialButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/bmotor1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="Genel Tanıtım"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp" />



 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution would be just put your buttons in LinearLayout and wrap it with ScrollView not everything with ScrollView. If my answer is not what you want could you provide more information? Like images of what you doing and how finished result should work.

Comment: Then idk what you trying to do. Need more details.

Comment: Scroolview for buttons under the videoview